# Design decision for mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, create-table

I want to represent a device who posses a led screen, a bunch of sensors, and some other properties. The thing is I know, in the future, we might need to store different kind of devices so I'm hesitating about how to represent in the database.

My first approach was a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE device_name (
 id STRING(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 led00 STRING(6) DEFAUTL "000000",...,
 sensor_name_status BOOL,
 sensor_name_data REAL,
 ....
 owner STRING(32) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES users(id));
```

This way I represent the owner and device id with a md5 token as identifier and I have one field for each led and sensor.

Other approach was:

```
CREATE TABLE devices (
id STRING(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
owner STRING(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES users(id));

CREATE TABLE sensors (
device_id STRING(32) NOT NULL,
status BOOL,
data REAL,
type INT(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (device_id,type)
FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES devices(id));

CREATE TABLE leds (
device_id STRING(32) NOT NULL,
value STRING(6) NOT NULL,
x INT(3) NOT NULL,
y INT(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (device_id,x,y),
FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES (devices));
```

The second alternative seems conceptually better deal for me, cause it allows me to insert new devices with a consistent access interface but I'm worried about performance if I have just like 1-3 device models maybe will be better to have one device table for each one.

What are your thoughts? Any criticism is welcome :)

Comment: Option 2 is your only real option if you have 'a bunch of sensors' - it will be more maintainable and more extnensible- in terms of speed - well unless you are talking millions of items it is not going to be a worry - JOIN is very efficient!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second approach is the right direction.  This is clear from the first line of your question:  "I want to represent a device who posses a led screen, a bunch of sensors, and some other properties."  You have three different entities in the real world.  Model them as three different entities.

Room for improvement.  Use auto-incremented integer primary keys for the ids.  I also prefer calling the `id` after the name of the table, so `DeviceId` is the primary key for that. That means that any join is "obvious" because the join fields are named the same or very similarly.

In addition, I think you need additional tables for `Sensors` and possibly `LED`s.  That is, the `type` information should be stored in a different table.

Here is my suggestion:

```
CREATE TABLE Devices (
    DeviceID int not nullauto_increment primary key
    Name varchar(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Owner_UserId int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Owner_UserId) REFERENCES users(Userid)
);

create table Sensors (
    SensorId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    Type int,
    Name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE sensors (
    DeviceID int NOT NULL,
    SensorID int not null,
    status BOOL,
    data REAL,
    primary key (DeviceID, SensorId)
    foreign key (DeviceID) REFERENCES devices(DeviceID),
    foreign key (SensorId) REFERENCES sensors(SensorID),
);

CREATE TABLE leds (
    DeviceID int not null,
    value varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    x INT(3) NOT NULL,
    y INT(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (DeviceID, x, y),
    FOREIGN KEY (DeviceID) REFERENCES devices(DeviceID)
);
```

In general, when creating tables, I also add two or three default columns at the end:

```
CreatedAt . . . the date/time when created (a timestamp column in MySQL)
CreatedBy . . . who created the column
CreatedOn . . . The server where the machine was created (if the system is going to span servers)
```

Comment: Thank you man, didnt expect so fast answer, sorry delay on marking as correct!!